# Martingales and Optimal Stopping. Prove: $E[M_T] = E[M_0]$

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

See Problem below.  How did they come up with the expression:

$$M_T = \sum \limits_{j=0}^{k} M_j I_{[T=j]}$$

All they told me for the problem statement was that $\{M_n, n \ge 0\}$ is a stochastic process,  I'm not understanding why they suddenly decided to add the sequence together to get $M_T$, why would it be like that?  I think they left out part of the problem statement.

[image: Optimal Stopping and Martingales]

[image: Optimal Stopping and Martingales]

Answer (score 2):

The stopping time is a partition of the sample space $\Omega$ and since it is bounded we have that:
$$ \Omega = \bigcup_{j=0}^k \{ T = j \} $$

So,
$$ 1 = \sum_{j=0}^k I_{ \{T=j\} } $$

And therefore:
$$ M_T = M_T\times 1 =  \sum_{j=0}^k M_TI_{ \{T=j\} } = \sum_{j=0}^k M_jI_{ \{T=j\} } $$

Comment: I think i understand...  $M_j$ gets filtered  by the $I_{\{T=j\}}$ function until j=T

Comment: I don't think I understand way you said. The point is just that on the set $\{T=j\}$ the value of $M_T$ is $M_j$ since $T=j$.